# JetBrains scope dimming feature/irritant

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Does anyone know what is this new feature JetBrains enabled for PhpStorm?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLrBqubrEJI

For some reason, only the function surrounding the caret is highlighted.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like some sort of "Focus mode" but that feature isn't yet available in PhpStorm. Probably this is coming from a 3rd party plugin. Try disabling all custom plugins at Settings | Plugins > click on a gear icon > "Disable All Downloaded Plugins", restart IDE and check the behavior after that.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitrii. Solved it. The setting that toggles this feature. Select "View" → "Highlight Only Current Declaration" or right click the line number/gutter and select the same. 


However, I've not narrowed down the plugin as I have many disabled plugins and it would take some time to sole each.

Comment: Yeah, that's a part of a Focus Mode. The feature isn't really publically available, you must've enabled it using vmoptions or using some older IDE version

Comment: I do have Internal's turned on. `idea.is.internal=true` for debugging plugins.

Comment: @Dmitrii Might also be the Rainbow Brackets plugin: https://github.com/izhangzhihao/intellij-rainbow-brackets#screenshots -- Scope highlighting. But I think it is "manual" (requires extra clicks/shortcuts).